# FullCalendar V4 on Angular 8: how to refresh data on "subscribe"

Tags: angular, typescript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I'm wondering how to refresh data in fullCalendar (V4) in Angular (typescript): I have try everything I found on documentation but nothing seems to work properly.

On "SAVE" it all works fine, all the data saves to database properly but after save I would like to reload data (with the id(s) generated from database) and refresh them (reload from zero if it's necessary) to the calendar.

Has anyone tried something similar?

Comment: Can you provide a minimal [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) to show your problem?

Comment: That's quite difficult, cause in the "background" I've got also NGRX and a real database service (not "on internet" at the moment),

Comment: Maybe you can mock something using [Angular firebase](https://angularfirebase.com/) or just use a datatable to store your content.

Comment: I will try... Not so simple anyway. In the meantime I really appreciate if someone could show me How to reload data (angular/fullcalendar v4) after the array that contains eventsource/events change.

Comment: Since we can't see how you've set up your event feed into fullCalendar it's really impossible to tell you what you need to do. There are generally 3 strategies you can follow: 1. [events as JSON feed](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed) (most recommended), 2. [events via custom function](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function) (2nd best), or 3. [static array of events](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-array) (less flexible, generally not recommended except for very simple cases). Have you adopted one of these three approaches?

Comment: If you have used approach 1. or 2. then whenever you want to tell fullCalendar to refresh the list of events you can simply the [refetchEvents](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-refetchEvents) method and it will automatically pull the data from the data source again. But if you supplied a simple list of events then this cannot work, instead you have to manually remove all the events and add a new event source containing the updated list.

Comment: In this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/fullcal-v3-10-0) you can find a minimal example, but its v3!

Comment: Okay, I've got it!!! 

I used the approach number 3 (cause my datas update in a subcription of an Observable from a NGRX store action).

So (wehen I got datas) I do:

            let evts = this.calendarApi.getEvents();
            evts.forEach(element => {
              element.remove();
            });
            this.calendarApi.addEventSource(this.mySource);
            this.calendarApi.rerenderEvents();

I think this is not so elegant...

Comment: I agree. I think approach number 2 might suit you better. You can give fullCalendar a callback containing any functionality you need in order to fetch the events and return them to the calendar.

Comment: I see your "stackblitz" comment here only now! Okay, I look at it!

Thank you so much !!!!!!!!